# How to get window size from cross-domain iframe in IE

Tags: javascript, iframe

In a cross domain scenario I need to know what's in the iframe size (width and height) when the javascript code running inside the iframe. (I can't climb to the parent because I'm in a cross domain iframe)
Note: I don't want to use jquery.
I tried several ways to get that info:

```
var w = window.innerWidth || window.document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth || document.body.offsetWidth
var h = window.innerHeight || window.document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight || document.body.offsetHeight
```

Comment: What is `this`? Why don't you provide more code as a context for where this code is and what you're doing?

Comment: There shouldn't be this. I removed it

Comment: So you have Javascript in an iframe. You're trying to get the size of what? The iframe? Or the parent window holding the iframe?

Comment: Exactly. I'm trying to get the iframe size.

Comment: Okay, and is the code you provided returning any values? Or is this just not working in IE?

Comment: It's just not working on IE. It's work for FF and Chrome

Comment: Okay, do you get any errors or just `0` or `""`? Did you know you have some weird code in there? In the middle of the second line, you have `|| viewportheight = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight` (notice the `viewportheight = ` part), and at the end of the same line, you have `offsetHeight`, not `document.body.offsetHeight` like you do in the first line for `offsetWidth`?

Comment: I get 0. The weird code is just copy pass mistake. I fixed it in the question body

Answer (score 0):

So, are you trying to access an iframe on another domain?
You can't, because of XSS protection.

Here's a similar question: [Get DOM content of cross-domain iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170925/get-dom-content-of-cross-domain-iframe)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

EDIT: Maybe this solution could give you an hint on what to do http://paulasmuth.com/blog/dynamic_height_crossdomain_iframe/ depending on the permissions you have on your pages.

Comment: I'm not trying to access another domain. I try to get the iframe size using javascript running on the same iframe

Comment: Oooh okay, now it's clearer! Yeah, it should be enough to do as dencey said.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the window size, use this(excluding the scrollbar size if there is):

```
var w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
```

If you want to get the document size, use this(excluding the scrollbar size if there is):

```
var w = document.documentElement.scrollWidth;
var h = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
```