# Getting parent width from Iframe doesn't work in Chrome or Opera browsers

Tags: javascript, html

I found a line of code here: `parent.document.body.clientWidth` [How can I get a parent window's height from within iFrame using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735072/how-can-i-get-a-parent-windows-height-from-within-iframe-using-jquery) that i use to find the width of the parent page from an iframe.

It works in Edge, IE 11, Firefox but not for Chrome or Opera.

Is there a fix or perhaps a different solution to the problem?

Example

**IFrame**

html

```
<body onresize="bodyRePr()">
    <script src="examplescript.js"></script>
    [...]
</body>
```

js

```
function bodyRePr(){
    if (parent.document.body.clientWidth > 720){
        document.getElementById("example").style.width = "460px";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("example").style.width = "100%";
    }
}
```

I see this error when opening the page in Opera, not sure what it means.
[image]

requested:

html is of another page including the iframe

```
<body onscroll="toggleMenu()" onload="startup()" onload="getBrowserInfo()" onresize="bodyRe()">
    [...]
    <nav id="profileMenu">
        <iframe id="profileMenuIframe"></iframe>
        <div onclick="closeProfileMenu()" class="closeBtn">&#9587;</div>
    </nav>
[...]
</body>
```

css

```
#profileMenu{
    z-index: 6;
    position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 500px; height: 100%;
    margin-left: -100%;
    background: rgb(30,30,30);
    transition: margin-left 0.2s;
}
#profileMenuIframe{
    width: 500px;
}
```

Comment: can you show you html as how you placed iframe ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Comment: @Tushar updated

Comment: why would you want to know the parents size? why is that important?

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon i want to resize the iframe when the window is smaller than 700px. however i couldn't use ´@media´ in css since i was making the iframe wider at that point.

Comment: you can't do that on any respectable browser, it would be a security hazard. the best you can do is make sure your content is presented nicely regardless the size is being rendered in.

Comment: Thanks @DavidDomain seems that's the problem i'm having, solution is a bit too advanced for me to understand quite yet.

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon I think i might do just that in this case. thanks for all the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't test frame/parent references **offline** in Chrome, using file:// URL's as shown in your example.

And you can't reference your **online** resources either, while testing offline, because that would be cross-site scripting.

To test your parent frame references, you either need to use a browser that supports offline URL's the same way it supports online URL's, or test both parent and frames using an HTTP server.